# jQuery hide / show class not changing css for future added elements

Tags: jquery, css, show-hide

How can I change the css using jQuery such that it takes effect for future elements as well?  I have an issue where I'm using $().show() to toggle the display on some elements, but then I append new elements with the same class, and they remain hidden.

```
<style type="text/css">
  .visibleState { display: none; }
</style>
<script>
  $('.visibleState').show();
  $('#appendHere').html('<div id="second" class="visibleState">* Second is NOT? visible</div>');
</script>
```

This has probably been asked, but I can't find it.  I tried using live() in different ways, but that didn't seem to work.  What's the right way to do this?

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/amorris/wykhv/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="imagetoolbar" content="false">
<meta http-equiv="imagetoolbar" content="no">
<style type="text/css">
.classname {
 color: red;
 font-size: 14px;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("button").onclick = function() {
        var ss = document.styleSheets;

        for (var i=0; i<ss.length; i++) {
            var rules = ss[i].cssRules || ss[i].rules;

            for (var j=0; j<rules.length; j++) {
                if (rules[j].selectorText === ".classname") {
                    rules[j].style.color = "green";
                }
            }
        }
    };
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h1 class="classname">Some red text</h1>

<button id="button">Make text green</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks - that works!  Here's a working fiddle using that http://jsfiddle.net/amorris/wykhv/2/

Comment: The other answers may indicate better practice, but this explains the best how to change the actual css properties.  Thanks again.

Comment: Pay attention, use method live to subscribe on events of existing and future elements. _(.live( events, handler ) - attach an event handler for all elements which match the current selector, now and in the future)_

Answer (score 3):

This is not how `live` works. `$('.visibleState').show();` will find all (currently existing) elements with the `visibleState` class, and show them. It does not alter the CSS rules of the `visibleState` style itself.

You could access these rules manually by tapping into `document.styleSheets`.

Comment: Thanks - it's not the best/usual practice to change css styles, so either I should be calling $('.visibleState').show()/hide() after I append new elements, or change the elements before I add them.

Comment: @Adam: yes, you could always have a global boolean javascript variable called `visibleState`, and whenever you append an object, you could call `.toggle(window.visibleState)`, and you'd set the element to be visible or hidden depending on the value of `window.visibleState`.

Answer (score 1):

I try to avoid using .show() and .hide() except in extremely simple cases. Instead, use classes with default and other wanted behavior. So your have your .visibleState class, and .visibleState.show { display:block; }

```
<style type="text/css">
  .visibleState { display: none; /* default hidden */ }
  .visibleState.show { display: block; }
</style>
<script>
  $('.visibleState').addClass('show');
  $('#appendHere').html('<div id="second" class="visibleState show">Second is NOW visible</div>');
</script>
```

Although I'd change your 'visibleState' class to something more semantically applicable, like 'defaultState'.

The way you are doing it now will not work because the function call of .show() hasn't been applied to your #second element.

Comment: Thanks - I have elements being dynamically added to a page, and a button which shows/hides a subset of those elements. It seems easier to toggle a the display properties of a single class, instead of having to know which of two classes are currently added... or am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: do something like element .child { display:none; /* default hidden */} element.show .child { display:block; } and all you have to do is add or remove the 'show' class instead of removing and adding each time. i'll update my response above to show this

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would probably be to have a containing parent which you add and remove a class from.  For example:

```
.shown .child{
    display: block;
}

.hidden .child{
    display:none;
}
```

```
<div id="parent" class="hidden">
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

```
$("#parent").removeClass("hidden").addClass("shown")
    .append("<div class='child'>this will now be shown</div>");
```

Any number of different css rules can be used in place of just showing and hiding.

Working example:  http://jsfiddle.net/xJ2Gh/

Comment: this is good but if you use knowledge of CSS order of operations, you don't need to remove the .hidden class to use the .show class. you just have to choose which one is the default state of that element. So do something like

element .child { display:none; /* default hidden */}
element.show .child { display:block; }

and all you have to do is add or remove the 'show' class instead of removing and adding each time.

Answer (score 1):

You can define some flag and change its value when show event is invoked:

```
var fired = false;
$('.visibleState').show(function(){
    fired = true;
});
```

After that, while you are sure the show event has finished, you can set up visibility of newly created elements based on this flag state:

```
$('#appendHere').html('<div id="second" class= "visibleState"' + (fired ? " style=\"display: block\"" : "") + ') >* Second is visible</div>');
```

Comment: Cool idea - that's a great way to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the js, so it's inline.

```
  $('#appendHere').html('<div id="second" class="visibleState" style="display: block;">* Second is NOT? visible</div>');
```

The inline style over-rides the style in the head, or in the stylesheet for that matter.

That's all that `show()` really does anyway.
Show and hide add and remove inline styles for the display property. Perhaps the visibililty property too, anyone?

Comment: Not `visibility`, only `display`. Additionally, it keeps track of whatever the previous display mode was, so that it doesn't set `display: block` to an element that was `display: inline-block;` before being hidden, for instance.